# Best practice for ensure user is logged in or out using cookieStore and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cookies, angularjs

Right now I am building an AngularJS based application on top of Ruby on Rails and using Devise for authentication. I have the server responding properly when a user authenticates successfully and when authentication fails. I guess my question is, using $cookieStore, what's the best practice for knowing if a user is logged in or not? There is a cookie that gets set by Rails called "myapp_session", but that session doesn't necessarily mean a user is logged in. Looking for ideas on how to use AngularJS to keep user online/offline management. I'll still be ensuring that requests that require authorization get authorized by the backend regardless of the solution.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can create an directive that set up the logged user when the application loads, for example, requesting the current user session on your server.

```
angular.module('Auth', [
        'ngCookies'
    ])
    .factory('Auth', ['$cookieStore', function ($cookieStore) {

        var _user = {};

        return {

            user : _user,

            set: function (_user) {
                // you can retrive a user setted from another page, like login sucessful page.
                existing_cookie_user = $cookieStore.get('current.user');
                _user =  _user || existing_cookie_user;
                $cookieStore.put('current.user', _user);
            },

            remove: function () {
                $cookieStore.remove('current.user', _user);
            }
        };
    }])
;
```

And set in your `run` method in `AppController`:

```
   .run(['Auth', 'UserRestService', function run(Auth, UserRestService) {

            var _user = UserRestService.requestCurrentUser();
            Auth.set(_user);
        }])
```

Of course if any request to the server return an `Http Status 401 - Unauthorized`, you need to call the `Auth.remove()` service to remove the user from cookie and redirect the user to login page.

I use this approach and works very well. You can also use the `localStorage`, but the user data will be persisted for a long time. Unless you set an expiration date for this authentication, I don't see as best practice.

Keep in mind to always verify the user credentials on your server site =)

**[EDIT]**

To listen to `401 - Unauthorized` server response, you can put an interceptor on your `$http` request, like this:

```
 .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($urlRouterProvider, $routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
        var interceptor = ['$location', '$q', function ($location, $q) {

            function success(response) {
                return response;
            }

            function error(response) {

                if (response.status === 401) {
                    $location.path('/login');
                    return $q.reject(response);
                }
                else {
                    return $q.reject(response);
                }
            }

            return function (promise) {
                return promise.then(success, error);
            };
        }];

        $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
    }])
```

Every call with `401` response, the user will be redirected to login page at `/login` path.

You will find a good example [here](http://www.frederiknakstad.com/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/)

Comment: This is a fantastic response. Thanks for the insight. It's been useful.

Comment: I get an error about `Unknown provider: $urlRouterProvider` with this.

Comment: Are you using angular v1.2?

Comment: Sorry to Ask... in your case, what is the UserRestService?

Comment: Its the angular $resource that loads the current user in server session via REST. I'm using the session management at the server side to avoid trust just in the client cookie.

Comment: Very nice, so you recommend that every time AngularJS request data or sends data to a web method, on the server we should check the user identify maybe by calling database or other mechanism? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's the best approach to work with secured data. I usually set these keys (like token and user email) in the request headers, so the server do the logic to verify the authenticity.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the cookie on your login callback with

```
$cookieStore.put('logged-in', some_value)
```

Then check for it when they enter your site with

```
.run(function($cookieStore) {
    if ($cookieStore.get('logged-in') === some_value) {
        let him enter
    }
    else {
        you shall not pass
    }
});
```

There might be more "correct" ways, but this works.

Answer (score 2):

If you're having problems making the accepted answer work, be wary, that as of Angular 1.3, a proper way of adding a new interceptor is by adding it to $httpProvider.interceptors, so instead of:

```
$httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
```

use:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
```