# Angularjs $http does not seem to understand "Set-Cookie" in the response

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I have a nodejs express REST api with Passport module for authentication.
A login method (GET) returns a cookie in the header. When I call it from Chrome it works fine, my cookie is set in my browser.

But if I call it through $http from Angularjs, the cookie is not set.

```
Set-Cookie:connect.sid=s%3Ad7cZf3DSnz-IbLA_eNjQr-YR.R%2FytSJyd9cEhX%2BTBkmAQ6WFcEHAuPJjdXk3oq3YyFfI; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

As you can see above, the Set-Cookie is present in the header of the http service response.

Perhaps HttpOnly may be the source of this problem? If yes, how can I change it? Here is my express configuration :

```
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(allowCrossDomain);
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser())
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'this is a secret' }));
    app.use(flash());
    //passport init
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
});
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: could you provide your angular method that call $http for login in please. can't tell what's wrong for now

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make sure to configure your $http request to use credentials.
From the XHR documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

> The most interesting capability exposed by both XMLHttpRequest and
>   Access Control is the ability to make "credentialed" requests that are
>   cognizant of HTTP Cookies and HTTP Authentication information.  By
>   default, in cross-site XMLHttpRequest invocations, browsers will not
>   send credentials.  A specific flag has to be set on the XMLHttpRequest
>   object when it is invoked.

You can use the options object to set the use of credentials, see

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

Example:

```
$http({withCredentials: true, ...}).get(...)
```

Comment: But AngularJS still doesn't understand `set-cookie` in the response.

Comment: I took me more than a day to realise that `withCredentials = true` not only tells browser to attach cookies on request, but also tells it to save new cookies on response. It's the same with ajax options for `fetch` function where `credentials: 'include'` must be applied to make browser sending and setting cookies on request and response. I.e. when sending `login` ajax request to a dedicated api, though no cookies are requiered, `withCredentials=true` must be set otherwise the received `sessionid` cookie will be available but the browser will not save it.

Answer (score 5):

How are you checking for the existence of the cookie?

`$http` is just a wrapper around the browser's XHR, just like jQuery's `$.ajax` and friends.  That means your browser will handle the cookies normally.

My guess is that the cookie *is* being set, but you're trying to read it through `document.cookie`.  `HttpOnly` prevents script from having access to the cookie.  **This is a good thing.**

`HttpOnly` helps mitigate against XSS attacks.  It makes it impossible for malicious script to steal a user's session token (and thus their login).  **Do not turn off `HttpOnly`.**

You should not need the cookie anyway.  Since `$http` is just a wrapper around XHR, the browser will automatically send the cookie the next time you make a request.  You can verify this by watching the requests in the Developer Tools' Network panel.

Comment: I'd edit the post to account for the specific requirement of setting withCredentials to true.

It won't send cookies without that and also the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.

Regarding the comments about HttpOnly that's a VERY good point +1 for making sure everything is secure.

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem by setting `{withCredential : true}` in the angular `$http` request and by setting :

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
```

in my express server configuration. By doing this, my cookie appears well in my browser cookies list.

Answer (score 2):

Below solution worked for me

In **Angular**, I  have used following code snippet using 
`withCredentials: true` for my request.

```
this._http.post(this._apiUrl + 'api/' + url, data, { withCredentials: true })
            .subscribe(data => { resolve(data) }, error => { this.showServerError(error)})
```

In Node, before I got the solution, I was just initializing **CORS** using

```
app.use(cors());
```

But, now I have implemented the following code snippet

```
app.use(cors({origin: [
   "http://localhost:5000"
 ], credentials: true}))
```

> Where http://localhost:5000 is my Angular application endpoint. You
>   can set this URL dynamically from config or .env file.

Hope that above solution will work for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by configuring `express.session`:

```
app.use(express.session({
  secret : 'this is a secret',
  cookie : {
    httpOnly : false,
    maxAge   : XXX // see text
  }
});
```

But I don't think Angular cares much about cookies, those are handled by the browser (and I agree with @josh3736 that you should keep `httpOnly` to `true`).

It might have something to do with your cookies being (browser-)session cookies. You can try and see if it works better by explicitly setting a `maxAge` for the cookie (in milliseconds).