# Angular : Wait for app run to get response

Tags: angularjs, authentication

As of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982868/angularjs-best-practice-for-ensure-user-is-logged-in-or-out-using-cookiestore), I'm trying to figure out if the user is logged in (using a token based authentication).

The scheme is following :

1/ The page loads, app run is called, and authenticated is set to false as default

```
app.run(function($http, UserService) {
    UserService.requestCurrentUser();

    $http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    $http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
});

app.constant('AUTHENTICATED', false);
```

2/ UserService call for its method requestCurrentUser() in which a http get is sent to the correct url with the token in its header.

- If token is correct, this sends back the user (success case, we're authenticated).
- If not, I get a permission error (error case, we're not authenticated).

This updates `currentUser`property and `AUTHENTICATED` constant.

```
app.factory('UserService', function ($http, $q, $window, AUTHENTICATED) {
    var _currentUser = {};

    return {
        
        getCurrentUser: function() {
            return _currentUser;
        },

        setCurrentUser: function(user) {
            _currentUser = user;
        },

        requestCurrentUser: function() {
            return $http.get('/accounts/api/').then(
                function (response) {
                    _currentUser = response.data;
                    AUTHENTICATED = true;
                },
                function (error) {
                    AUTHENTICATED = false;
                }
            );
        },
    };
});
```

3/ Controller is called and `authenticated` and `currentUser` scope values are updated.

```
app.controller('AuthCtrl', function ($scope, AuthService, UserService, AUTHENTICATED) {
    $scope.authenticated = AUTHENTICATED;
    $scope.currentUser = UserService.getCurrentUser();
});
```

Problem is that controller tries to reach the values before `requestCurrentUser` method (launched in app run) has received a response. So **where should I launch `requestCurrentUser` to get the expected behavior ?**

Thanks

Comment: strategy can be dependent on whether paths need to be blocked or not and which router is used. For example in ui-router a single parent state resolve can be used and all routes that require auth can be set as child states , none of which are accessible if parent resolve gets rejected. Other strategies include using route start event to resolve authentication

Comment: Lots of tutorials around on this subject

Comment: Any exemple of such tutorial ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

What you could do it wrap your user state object in a parent object. For example:

```
var state = {
    _currentUser: {}
};

return {
    getUserState: function(){ return state; }
};
```

Then inside your controller:

```
$scope.state = UserService.getUserState();
```

This way, when your user updates (no matter when or how in your service), anything bound to the state will receive the update. So your controller will have access to `state._currentUser` when it is available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as what I'm experiencing should be quite common, I'm wondering if there is a best practice for what I'm trying to achieve. I'm new on angular and I think that maybe I should rethink my structure more globally ? Maybe app.run() is not the place to request the current user.

Comment: Having a service for managing your user state is a good choice. If you wrap the user in a container object, and wrap any async related processes in promises you should be good. That way you can inject your user service anywhere and do what you want with it. There are no specific standards for functionality layout like user auth, but you should be able to find plenty of examples. Keep experimenting and decide what is best for you.